# Food makes people what fuel does cars

Tags: sentence-meaning

I'm wondering if the following sentence can correctly mean "Just as fuel provides cars with energy, so food provides people with energy," or "Just as fuel makes cars full of energy, so food makes people full of energy."

> Food makes people what fuel does cars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you're trying to do there, but it doesn't work.

The first problem is that you've used "what" to stand in for the way food affects people. But "what" is a pronoun and "the way" is an adverbial, so "what" cannot hold the place of "the way". Let's try with "as" instead:

> Food makes people **as** fuel does cars.

This sentence could plausibly have the meaning you intend, so it's at least ambiguous, but very few English speakers reading it would parse it that way. They would understand something like:

> Food makes people, and fuel does cars, and these two things are similar.

While it's true that food makes people, it doesn't make sense to say fuel "does" cars.

Here's two fixes that have the meaning you intend:

> Food does to people what fuel does to cars. (keeping the "what" element)
> Food makes people feel as fuel makes cars feel. (keeping the "make" element)

Comment: Charles Dickens wrote this sentence: "Poetry makes life what light and music do the stage."

Comment: @Apollyon Nobody reading that today would parse that correctly the first time through. I had to read it several times to figure out its structure. It's possible people spoke that way in Dickens's time, or he was using poetic license to force the language into new shapes.

Comment: Thank you. That's what prompted me to start this thread: to investigate whether Dickens's sentence structure is valid in contemporary English.

Answer (score 0):

At two extra words

> "Food is to people what fuel is to cars", or
>
> "Food makes people the same way fuel does cars" or
>
> "Food for people is same as fuel for cars"

If you want to get away with "Idiomatic" murder, you may say something like

> "Food maketh people same way fuel runneth cars"

It is both archaic and would be  understood.

Comment: Are you a native speaker?

Comment: I am not a native speaker.

Answer (score -2):

In itself, that sentence means nothing, it is just a bunch of words put together.

The first fix needed is adding the "to":

> Food makes **to** people what fuel does **to** cars.

and the second fix is to use the proper verb:

> Food **is** to people what fuel **is** to cars.

Then it suddenly gets a proper clear meaning: "food is the fuel of people".

Of course, this is the kind of sentence you could find in some intelligence tests, and might not be encountered often during everyday chats.

Note: thanks to @PeterJennings for waking me up, to write down what I actually had in mind.

Comment: Sorry virolino, but **Food makes to people what fuel does to cars** is not a fix. It is still a bunch of words that does not make much sense to a native English speaker. Although it is unlikely to be used in everyday conversation you could say **Food is to people as fuel is to cars**.

Comment: @PeterJennings: you are totally right, I had the right thinking but the wrong writing. I updated the answer. +1